# Поиск веса минимального маршрута

Tags: c#, алгоритм, рекурсия

Задание.

Дано прямоугольное поле D размером (N, M) клеток (двумерный массив). В каждой клетке
написано число – вес клетки. Из клетки (a, b) можно попасть в клетки (a + 1, b),  (a, b + 1) или (a + 1, b + 1). Вам надо попасть из клетки (0, 0) в клетку (N – 1, M – 1). Вес маршрута вычисляется как сумма весов посещенных клеток. Найдите вес минимального маршрута из (0, 0) в (N – 1, M – 1). Короче, вот формула:

```
G(0, 0) = D[0, 0]

G(i, 0) = G(i - 1, 0) + D[i, 0], i > 0

G(0, j) = G(0, j - 1) + D[0, j], j > 0

G(i, j) = min(G(i - 1, j - 1), G(i - 1, j), G(i, j - 1)) + D[i, j], i > 0, j > 0

F(D) = G(N - 1, M - 1)
```

Никак не получается написать правильно работающую рекурсивную функцию которая это все вычисляет. Вот мой вариант, но считает неверно. В чем ошибка? Как будет правильно?

```
public static int sum =0;
static int G(int i, int j, int[,] D)
    {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            return D[0, 0];
        if (j==0&&i!=0)
        { sum = G(i - 1, 0,D) + D[i, 0];
        return G(i - 1, 0, D);
        }
        if (i==0&&j!=0)
        {
            sum = G(0, j - 1, D) + D[0, j];
            return G(0, j - 1, D);
        }
        if (i!=0&j!=0)
        {
            sum = Math.Min(Math.Min(G(i - 1, j - 1, D), G(i - 1, j, D)), G(i, j - 1, D)) + D[i, j];
            return G(i - 1, j - 1, D);
        }
        return 1;

    }
```

Переписал функцию без суммы, все ровно считает неправильно.

```
        static int G(int i, int j, int[,] D)
    {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0)
        {
            return D[0, 0];
        }
        if (j==0&&i!=0)
        {
            return G(i - 1, 0, D) + D[i, 0];
        }
        if (i==0&&j!=0)
        {
            return G(0, j - 1, D) + D[0, j];
        }
        if (i!=0&j!=0)
        {
            return Math.Min(Math.Min(G(i - 1, j - 1, D), G(i - 1, j, D)), G(i, j - 1, D)) + D[i, j];
        }
        return 1;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну смотрите сами. У вас написано:

> G(i, 0) = G(i - 1, 0) + D[i, 0], i > 0

А что в коде?

```
if (j==0&&i!=0)
{ sum = G(i - 1, 0,D) + D[i, 0];
return G(i - 1, 0, D);
}
```

Для чего вам `sum` и что вы возвращаете?

**Обновление**

Вы пытаетесь что-то не то соптимизировать. Дело в том, что при рекурсивном вызове у вас одна и та же клетка будет просматриваться много раз, а некоторые просмотренные клетки не войдут в финальную сумму. Так что непонятно, что вы считаете.

[[@Valeriy Karchov](/users/2570/valeriy-karchov)](/users/2570/valeriy-karchov): Алгоритм кажется правильным, по идее стандартное применение динамического программирования.

Если отбросить от оптимального пути в клетку `[i, j]` последнее движение, то получится очевидно оптимальный путь в предпоследнюю клетку. Поскольку эта клетка либо `[i-1, j]`, либо `[i, j-1]`, либо `[i-1, j-1]`, то выбрать оптимальный путь в клетку `[i, j]` сводится к выбору из трёх вариантов (`min(G(i - 1, j - 1), G(i - 1, j), G(i, j - 1)) + D[i, j]`).

Вроде всё верно?

Comment: Sum для хранения суммы весов посещенных клеток. А в коде я пытаюсь считать посещенные клетки при G(i,0).

Comment: @VladD, а мне вот кажется, что алгоритм, предложенный @vados, не всегда возвратит минимальный путь, например, для такого массива:

    0 4 1 9 9
    3 7 7 1 9
    3 7 7 4 9
    9 3 3 2 9
    9 9 9 9 9

Comment: В алгоритме все верно, так как он дан в заданий. Проблема с написанием рекурсивной функции по этому алгоритму.

Comment: @VladD, да, всё верно, спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 0):

Да напишите обычный [UCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) поиск в графе. Результирующий путь, найденный алгоритмом будет иметь наименьший вес.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

static class WeightGrid
{
    private static int weight(int[,] a, int x, int y, int w)
    {
        int m = a.GetLength(0);
        int n = a.GetLength(1);
        if (x == m && y == n)
        {
            return w;
        }
        if (x == m || y == n)
        {
            return Int32.MaxValue;
        }
        w += a[x, y];
        return Math.Min(weight(a, x + 1, y, w),
               Math.Min(weight(a, x, y + 1, w),
                        weight(a, x + 1, y + 1, w)));
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] a = {
            { 0, 4, 1, 9, 9 },
            { 3, 7, 7, 1, 9 },
            { 3, 7, 7, 4, 9 },
            { 9, 3, 3, 2, 9 },
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }
        };
        Console.WriteLine(weight(a, 0, 0, 0));
    }
}
```